# How to use Function<? super String, ? extends String>

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, proxy, spring-webflux

I am trying to connect to a server using a proxy, but the object I am creating forces me to create a `Function <? super string, ? extends String>`, but I don't know how to use it. How does this `Function` work? He asks me for the password

My code:

```
Function<? super String, ? extends String> pwd = username -> passProxy;
HttpClient httpClientAux = HttpClient.create().tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient.proxy(
                proxy -> proxy.type(ProxyProvider.Proxy.HTTP).address(new InetSocketAddress(urlProxy, 8080)).username(usuarioProxy).password(pwd)));
ReactorClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClientAux);
this.myWebClient = webClientBuilder.clientConnector(connector).build();
```

Comment: What’s the problem with your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Function` Represents a function that accepts one argument and produces a result.

Function has basically two type arguments first is INPUT argument type and second is for OUTPUT return type

```
Function<? super String, ? extends Integer> checkvalue = (str) -> str.length(); 
// takes String as parameter and produce length as Integer
```

In your case `Function <? super string? extends String>` take username string as parameter and produce as password string

As from doc https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/api/reactor/netty/tcp/ProxyProvider.Builder.html#password-java.util.function.Function-

For more about `Function` https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces